# Cakephp variable problem - using globals?

Tags: php, cakephp, global-variables

I'm trying to run an irc bot with cakephp. My problem is referencing the connection, I can pass it through functions but seems a silly solution when I'm writing dozens of functions all requiring the same variable. The way I did it was through a global variable $socket. It seems cakephp doesn't support global variables, at least not in the traditional sense.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
$socket = fsockopen($config['server'], $config['port']);
```

The main function I will keep calling is send_data(), which communicates with the server.

```
function send_data($cmd, $msg = null, $socket = null)
{
                  if($msg == null)
                        {
                                fwrite($socket, $cmd."\r\n");
                                echo '<strong>'.$cmd.'</strong><br />';
                                ob_flush();
                        } else {

                                fwrite($socket, $cmd.' '.$msg."\r\n");
                                echo '<strong>'.$cmd.' '.$msg.'</strong><br />';
                                ob_flush();
                        }
}
```

So basically every time I have to call the send_data function, which I do many times, I have to reference $socket. Is there a way to make it persist in cakephp?

Comment: That's not how you define a global scope reference. You are passing it as parameter. And unless you wrote `global $socket;` before the `=fsockopen(` assignment, it probably didn't even become an actual global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CakePHP way would be to add the socket to the model so you can then refer to it with `$this->ModelName->socket`. In this case you could put the send_data() function into the same model and use `$this->socket` inside it.

If this is needed in several models you can add it to `app_model.php` so it applies to every model or make a component to use in controllers.

Comment: Hmm I think a problem I'm running to is I can't run functions inside the model. Specifically this code: $socket = fsockopen($config['server'], $config['port']);

Comment: You can put the initialization function into `__construct()`, for example: `$socket = null; function __construct( $id = false, $table = null, $ds = null ) { $this->socket = fsockopen( ... ); return parent::__construct( $id, $table, $ds ); }`

Answer (score 0):

I partially agree with Juhana on this in which you should segregate the code via a model, not as a component. If you were to follow a true MVC pattern, you could stick it in a model, but a behavior might be the best practice.

I'd suggest looking into behaviors and see if it works with your data model.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1071/Behaviors